# Need a name for a specific System Info / CPU + Mem Usage Win 7 Gadget?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget, sidebar

I would like to know the name of this gadget:

[image]

Anybody got any idea what's it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer because I think I've located it.

This is probably Multimeter, last version number 2.10, created by Johan Bourtembour, better known as [SFkilla](http://www.sfkilla.com/), and having had at its height a 100000 member [community](http://thehobbylounge.com/forum/) founded around it, and which was unfortunately closed down. This gadget was highly skinable, and had hundreds of skins available by the (now defunct) community.

I found a possible download from [here](http://p.download.uol.com.br/superdownloads/utilitarios/68640_multimeter_210.zip), which was tested fine by Avast.

Below is one example skin published [here](http://forum.xcpus.com/software/16114-multimeter-sidebar-gadget-core-i7.html), where is also explained how to use this gadget:

[image]

Comment: Do you know the Temperature Gadget in the picture, perhaps?

Comment: I think it's all the same gadget, just a different skin.

Answer (score 0):

If the gadgets has an Options button, click it:

[image: image1]

You'll then see the gadget's name:

[image: image2]

Comment: I know, I'm still looking for its name, since I don't have the gadget.